# Get key value of first item in object

Tags: javascript

I have the following object which defines the end and start times for a paragraph:

```
var times = {
 "p1": [24.500, 29.268],
 "p2": [29.268, 29.441],
 "p3": [29.441, 29.640]
};
```

I wish to call `updateCurrentParagraph` when the paragraph changes:

```
vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {

    var t = this.currentTime;
    for (var key in times) {
       if (t >= times[key][0] && t < times[key][1])
       {
           updateCurrentParagraph(key);
           return;
       }
    }

    // at end of audio
    if (times[times.length-1][1] == t){
        updateCurrentParagraph(???);
        return;
    }

    updateCurrentParagraph("unknown");
    return;

});
```

What do I do at `???` to get "p3"?

Comment: `Object.keys(times)[0]`??

Comment: what is `first_paragraph`?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: first you need to define `first_paragraph` before assigning, then add `times.p1=first_paragraph`

Comment: Updated question to make it clear.

Comment: do you like to get the key with the greates value of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Object.keys` method by passing your object as *argument*.

```
var key = Object.keys(times)[0];
var values = times[key]
```

Comment: I dont think this is reliable as key in object doesnt guarantee sequence.

Comment: @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut Would that be Object.keys(times[times.length-1]) for the last key? I've updated my question.

Comment: No, for the last key is : `var lastKey = Object.keys(times)[times.length-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You could save the last key which has the right time for checking after the loop, if the properties are not ordered.

```
vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
    var t = this.currentTime,
        last;
    for (var key in times) {
        if (times[key][0] >= t && times[key][1] < t) {
            updateCurrentParagraph(key);
            return;
        }
        if (times[key][1] === t) {
            last = key;
        }
    }

    // at end of audio
    if (last) {
        updateCurrentParagraph(last);
        return;
    }

    updateCurrentParagraph("unknown");
    return;
});
```